# Asp.Net MVC3 View Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Based on this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) i am trying to make my own project, but i have a problem

**Visual Studio 2010 .net 4.0**

**SQL 2008 R2**

**My Database Table**

```
Iller

ID int
ILKod varchar(5)
IlAciklama nchar(20)
```

**My Model**

```
 namespace BilgiBankasi.Models
{
    public class Iller
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int ILKod { get; set; }

        public string IlAciklama { get; set; }
    }

    public class BilgiBankasiEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Iller> Iller { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**My Controller**

```
namespace BilgiBankasi.Controllers
{
    public class IlTestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /IlTest/

        BilgiBankasiEntities _db = new BilgiBankasiEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _db.Iller.ToList();
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**My View**

```
@model IEnumerable<BilgiBankasi.Models.Iller>
```

In this situation i get this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BilgiBankasi.Iller]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BilgiBankasi.Models.Iller]'.

But when i use

This comes from Model.edmx

```
@model IEnumerable<BilgiBankasi.Iller>
```

works great.

What am i missing ? Am i doing something wrong or is there a bug? The Scaffolding from model doesn't work either. I create all views myself.

Comment: try `var model = _db.Iller.ToList().AsEnumerable();`

Comment: i tried that too the error is The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[BilgiBankasi.Iller]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BilgiBankasi.Models.Iller]'.

Comment: You are using `DbContext` API, but it seems you have a `.edmx` (`ObjectContext` API) file too, can you please more explain? Clean and ReBuild the entire solution, ma be helpful too.

Comment: The fact that it is reporting BilgiBankasi.Iller, not the one in Models, tells me that it isn't using your model type. Presumably there is a BilgiBankasi.Iller from the edmx/dbml.

Comment: Agree with Marc. There must be a `BilgiBankasi.Iller` hanging around somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. connection string was **System.Data.Entity** and i change to **System.Data.Sqlclient**

Thanks everyone for spending time.